# How to get recordset from internal call to stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb

I have a stored procedure, internally I want to call another procedure that returns a record set, how do I get an navigate the record set returned by the stored procedure via the 'CALL' ?

[edit] I've been trying to use a TEMPORARY TABLE as suggested, but having problems:

```
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_HeadOfDepts;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tbl_HeadOfDepts (biDept_id tinyint(4))
    INSERT INTO tbl_HeadOfDepts CALL rsHeadOfAnyDepartments(vcCompKey, biWho_id);
```

I need to use CALL because 'rsHeadOfAnyDepartments' is not a function, but this will not be accepted.

Work in progress, but what I have so far that is not accepted by editor:

```
    BEGIN
    #--
    # Procedure:
    #   rsWhoCanIaccess
    #
    # Parameters:
    #   vcCompKey, the key corresponding to the company
    #   biWho_id, the id of the person to check access for
    #
    # Returns:
    #   recordset containing all the people this person can access
    #--
        DECLARE tiSuperUser tinyint(4); 
        DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
            BEGIN
                GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 @sqlstate = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, 
                @errno = MYSQL_ERRNO, @text = MESSAGE_TEXT;
                CALL procLogError(vcCompKey, CONCAT("rsWhoCanIaccess: "
                                        ,@errno, " (", @sqlstate, "): ", @text));
            END;        
    #Is this user a super user?
        SELECT tiIsSuperUser(vcCompKey, biWho_id) INTO tiSuperUser;
        SET tiSuperUser = 0;#Hack for testing
        IF (tiSuperUser = 1) THEN
    #The user is a superuser, return everyone in the company
            SELECT 
                t1.biPerson_id 
            FROM 
                tbl_people t1
            INNER JOIN
                tbl_companies t2
            ON
                t1.biCompany_id=t2.biCompany_id
            AND
                t2.vcKey=vcCompKey;         
        ELSE            
    #User is not a superuser, is the user head of any departments?
            DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_HeadOfDepts;
            CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tbl_HeadOfDepts (biDept_id tinyint(4))
            INSERT INTO tbl_HeadOfDepts CALL rsHeadOfAnyDepartments(vcCompKey, biWho_id);

            SELECT * FROM tbl_HeadOfDepts;
        END IF;
    END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, stored procedures can produce result sets, but not consume them directly as output from inner calls to other stored procedures. The best that you can do performance-wise is to populate a non-temporary work table and use the results.

Depending on your software and the reality of multiple callers concurrently, you might need to include a session id concept with an auto_increment (`AI`) column in some control table. This would ensure that with concurrency, multiple callers are not stomping on each other's rows, thus making it non-viable.

How that session would work, at a high level, is the following. The inner stored proc would be handed an `AI` value (`theSession`) from the control table, use it to populate a safely segmented session in the work table, and return as an `out` parameter to the outer (calling) stored proc. That outer one could then safely use those rows, and clean up at the end (`delete from workTable where sessionId=theSession`).

Why do I suggest a non-temporary work table? To be clear, the work table would be non-temporary. First of all there is the hassle of getting the `if exists drop` to work. Most importantly, though, it is about performance. DDL calls for temporary table creation are not inexpensive. You will only believe this when you do performance testing to see what I mean. It may seem trivial, but in trivial operations, those DDL calls for creation could very well account for the lion share of the time necessary for the inner stored proc to complete.

Answer (score 1):

> internally I want to call another procedure that returns a record set,

In your inner procedure create a `TEMPORARY TABLE` and populate that temp table saying `insert into your_temp_table select query`. then you can use that same temp table in your outer query anywhere.

It can even be a normal table as well and need not be temporary table. Also make sure to `DROP` the table once your procedure computation done as clean-up.

That's wrong per your comment. You should do it like below (a sample code)

```
create procedure rsHeadOfAnyDepartments(vcCompKey varchar(10), biWho_id int)
as
begin
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_HeadOfDepts; 
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tbl_HeadOfDepts(col1 int, col2 varchar(10), col3 varchar(30));

INSERT INTO tbl_HeadOfDepts
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM tblTest;    
end
```

Comment: @SPlatten, Try it and see for yourself ... absolutely it will work.

Comment: I'm not sure of how to do this, I've tried this: DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_HeadOfDepts;
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tbl_HeadOfDepts AS
   INSERT INTO tbl_HeadOfDepts CALL rsHeadOfAnyDepartments(vcCompKey, biWho_id);

Comment: @SPlatten, that's wrong. See edit in answer if that helps.

Comment: I can't call the procedure with a 'SELECT' its a stored procedure that returns a recordset, this can only be called with a 'CALL'

Comment: What you mean by `recordset`?

Comment: It doesn't return a single value but can be multiple rows of values.

Comment: @SPlatten, that shouldn't be an issue at all. See edit again, that's a sample ... do changes accordingly and it should work fine.

Comment: You cannot call a stored procedure with 'SELECT' this only works with functions and I am using a stored procedure which can only be called with a 'CALL'.

Comment: @SPlatten, did you read the answer carefully? I know how to execute a stored proc. Anyways, ...

Comment: I don't understand how that solves my problem, the issue is the stored procedure returns a set of rows and I need to get these into the temporary table somehow so I can iterate.