# How to call a stored procedure passing the result from another stored procedure as parameter?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

In pseudocode, this is exactly what I'm trying to achieve:

```
MAIN STORED PROCEDURE

    ids = CALL GetListOfIds(_user) 

    FOREACH (id in ids) 
        CALL AnotherStoredProcedure(id)
```

Comment: I believe this earlier answer of mine will be of assistance http://stackoverflow.com/a/37635488

Comment: But what you would do is call the first one, populate another table (does not *need* to be a temp table, it can be session-based permanent table, as in your session # returned in an **OUT** parameter). Then your wrapping stored proc uses either the whole table's data or the session-specific data that is segmented for you (a column with your session # in it) if it is multi-user, concurrency

Comment: What if I add a new View to my database?

Comment: Sorry, I rather mean, what if I duplicate my other stored procedure code and execute a query in the main stored procedure? may I then iterate those results somehow?

Comment: The first comment under your question says what you can do in general. That is for rows. Those rows can be in a temp table or permanent table. If you are not talking rows, then an OUT parameter. That is what those answers are for (not little comment boxes) :p

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get recordset from internal call to stored procedure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37633369/how-to-get-recordset-from-internal-call-to-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is partially or mostly answered in this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37635488) of mine (and I am sure by others before me). The pseudo code would be the following (using your pseudo code and adding a bit).

MAIN STORED PROCEDURE (a.k.a. Main)

```
CALL GetListOfIds(_user) 
  Note, the above stored proc populates either (A1) a temp table
  or (A2) a permanent table. When I say either, it means you choose
  ahead of time your strategy. In the case of (A2), an OUT parameter
  is filled in to alert the call of its session# (so the call is 
  more like: CALL GetListOfIds(_user,mySession) ).

Ok, we have returned at this point back to Main.

Now it is decision time, again, below for choice B.
```

**Choice B1:**

[Cursor](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cursors.html)

```
A Cursor is used to iterate thru a select stmt result against the
table strategy chosen (A1 or A2). Values are fetched into variables.
So let's call this Cursor Fetch.

FOREACH (fetch from Cursor Fetch into vars) 
    CALL AnotherStoredProcedure(with those vars)

or
```

**Choice B2:**

```
(Always and I mean always more performant, but not always possible):
Figure out the necessary sql calls to Update with a Join Pattern
or work thru other steps necessary without a cursor to arrive at 
your destination. Which may include the creation of other 
temporary tables or the use of permanent work tables (session-based 
or not), depending on concurrency issues (other users doing the 
same thing at the same time)
```

Note, if you are the only person or, say, maintenance routine, that has any chance of working with the above tables at any time while the above is occurring, then the notion of sessions and session#'s simply don't apply. In that case, you are merely free to use the tables as there are no concurrency issues. At least with those work tables.