# How to join the result set of two stored procedures

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which contains more that 25 queries and pass the line limit of MySQL stored procedure causing memory exhausted error.

So what I want is to divide it into two stored procedures and create a third stored procedure to union the two procedures. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What have you done so far?? Show us something to help you out..

Comment: this is exactly what i want to do but in mysql   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292069/union-the-results-of-multiple-stored-procedures

Comment: maybe [**THIS**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637288/can-a-stored-procedure-function-return-a-table) help, but looks like isnt possible.

Comment: I answered similar [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37635488)

Comment: okay at least is there a way i can put all my queries in on store procedure . i mean if there is a way to bypass the memory exhausted error ?

Comment: Maybe your query needs a facelift so it is not exhausting memory. We lack anything to work with here.

Comment: you probably have a stored procedure that needs a lot of improving!!

Answer (score -1):

Just push the results of both sp calls into a temp table:

```
/*Create a table with the same columns that the sp returns*/
CREATE TABLE #tempblahblah(blahblahblah NVARCHAR(50))

INSERT #tempblahblah ( blahblahblah )
 EXEC MyStored 0

INSERT #tempblahblah ( blahblahblah )
 EXEC MyStored 1

SELECT * FROM #tempblahblah
```