# SELECT .. INTO returns more than one rows - Mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, insert, insert-into

i have a basic stored procedure

```
DECLARE user_o VARCHAR(50);

SELECT user_name INTO user_o FROM users WHERE topic_id = 54 AND entry_time BETWEEN 
2017-09-17 AND date_add( CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 DAY) ORDER BY entry_time ASC 
LIMIT 10;
```

this throws me error #1172 sql returns more than one rows. no idea why?

my goal is to have this result set

```
user_name |  user_o
  mike       mike
  liz        liz
  helen      helen
  her        her
```

Comment: Does the user_o table already exist?

Comment: @tom damn . i forgot to add FROM statement. edited question. thanks for pointing it

Comment: users inclludes user_name, topic_id, entry_time and user_o is a declaration

Answer (score 2):

Its because you are inserting the result 'INTO' a variable and because the result is more than a single value, hence the error.

You have a limit of 10, try changing to 1, that will fix it, if you want multiple values returned then you need to manage these in a recordset.

Comment: yes but what i want to do is: take 'mike' form table than put it into the 'user_o'. Than do this for every 'user_name' inside 'users' table. i want 10 user name not 1.  any more detailed explanation for this?

Comment: try this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37633369/how-to-get-recordset-from-internal-call-to-stored-procedure